# Wrong data type accept in sqlite while creating table

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I have planed to create a editor for sqlite, I have created many part successfully but when I enter the create statement it is created successfully, but when I created with wrong data type it is also created successfully.
1) How is it possible?
2) If it is created, is it will affect in future.
3) How can I control this.

I told about the below statement

```
CREATE TABLE tb_merbinee(name TEXeT,AGE INTEGER,Mark INTEGER);
```

Comment: Consider reading the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

Answer (score -1):

As of my knowledge `sqlite` treats every datatype as `varchar`. there is no difference between varchar, text & int in `sqlite`.